# UPDATE não funcionando com ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

O problema é o seguinte, eu tenho um formulário de edição cujos dados são enviados por `ajax`. Eis o código:

```
$("#edit_rua").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var nome = $("#nome_rua2").val();
  var cod = $("#cod_rua").val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "cod_ajax/muda_rua.php",
      data: "id="+id+"&nome1="+nome+"&cod="+cod,
      success: function(e){
          alert(e);
          $(".nome"+id).html(nome);
          $(".cod"+id).html(cod);
      }
  })
});
```

Eu dei um `alert()` no `nome`, ele devolve bem o valor, dei um `alert` dentro do `muda_rua.php`, devolve bem, no entanto, sempre que dá o `UPDATE`, ele não atualiza, apenas devolve `0`, e se eu digitar `1`, ele insere `1`.

Aqui está o código do `muda_rua.php`

```
<?php
require "ligacao_bd.php";
$nome=$_POST['nome1'];
$cod=$_POST['cod'];
echo $nome;
$insert=mysql_query("UPDATE nome_tabela SET nome = '$nome' AND cod_postal = '$cod' where id = '".$_POST['id']."'") or die("ERRO 1!!!");
?>
```

Ele não dá o erro do `mysql_error()`, e se eu retirar o campo do nome do `UPDATE`, ele atualiza o código postal.

> Sei que o `mysql` está `deprecated` mas o programador antigo usava-o e ele tem mais de 100 páginas a usá-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua `SQL` está errada, o erro é porque no `SET` os campos são separados por ***virgula*** e na `SQL` da pergunta está o `AND`, exemplo corrigido:

```
$insert=mysql_query("UPDATE nome_tabela SET nome = '$nome', cod_postal = '$cod' where id = '".$_POST['id']."'") or die("ERRO 1!!!");
```

Comment: Obrigado! Resultou, irei dar a sua resposta como aceite em breve. Poderia explicar porque ele não dava erro no `mysql`?

Comment: @I_like_trains essa de dar erro ou não pode ser alguma configuração no `PHP`.